# Managing a session's variable in a model class with asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, session, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model

I have an asp.net mvc4 application in which i have this snippet:

```
   public bool Logout() {
            try {
                session["user"] = null;
                return true;
            }
            catch {
                return false;
            }
                          }
```

when i put this code in a controller it's works but if i put it in a model class it didn't.
the problem is in the `session["user"] = null;` .

So how can i manage the session's variables in a model class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality should not be in a view model. The model should be used for passing data from controllers to views for displaying, and receiving submitted data from views.

See a question like [What is a ViewModel in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11064316/what-is-viewmodel-in-mvc) to get a better explanation.

A logout function should be an action on a controller. Something like:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
{
    Session["user"] = null;

    // Redirect user to homepage
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In class access by the current context :

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["user"]....
```